# Easiest way to get the substring by eliminating the unwanted string in C#

Tags: c#, substring

I am trying to read the below string which is an OCR extracted text.

**ex-1.** `" My name is jack sparrow:”`

Here when I search for the string `"name is jack"` the output what i am expecting is `"name{99.03} is{85.37} jack{95.42}"` from the below string (with the first bracket values on the right side of the string extracted)

**ex-2.** `" My{99.64} name{99.03} is{85.37} jack{95.42} sparrow:{99.26}"`

I am using the below code to get `"name is jack"` which is working perfectly but cannot get the above expected output because of the brackets in ex-2 string.

```
                int pFrom = result.ToLower().IndexOf(startWord) + startWord.Length;
                int pTo = result.ToLower().IndexOf(endWord, pFrom);
                result = result.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom).Trim();
```

Any help would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am utterly confused. Where do the brackets come from?

Comment: And from my OCR-Experience: You won't be happy with any of `ToLower` or `ToUpper` (looking at YOU, turquish 'i') ... probably not with anything other than a fuzzy search (or similar).

Comment: brackets string is completely a different string. When i fetch the data, I will get one string with percentage(ex-2) and one without(ex-1). brackets will only have percentage.

Comment: Exactly. No worries, I should have been more clearer in my explanation. Just wanted to keep it simple for people to not get confused.

Comment: Have you thought about tokenizing that? For example you would Split ex1 into `string[]{" My", "name", "is", "jack"}` and ex2 into `string[]{" My{99.64}", "yadda yadda", ...}` then you could get to your desired output by using the same indexes ...

Comment: But for that i the percentage should be present after each and every word. so let's take one example "my name is jack{99.64} and i want to jump into the sea{42.4}". Here I have only 2 brackets but multiple words. Not sure if that works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you found your search string in ex1 => Index 4..15

```
              1
    0123456789012345
ex1: My name is jack sparrow:
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ex2: My{99.64} name{99.03} is{85.37} jack{95.42} sparrow:{99.26}
```

Then we tokenize:

```
ex1 [" My","name","is","jack","sparrow:"]
ex2 [" My{99.64}","name{99.03}","is{85.37}","jack{95.42}","sparrow:{99.26}"]
```

Then we can find indices:

```
" My" - length = 3 , startIndex was 4 -> nope, 
we add a space, so we are at (string-)index 4 which is equal to start
So, arrayindex 1 is in => [1]

"name" - length = 4 , 4 + 4 + 1 (whitespace) = 9
9 is < 15 => array-index 2 is still in => [1,2]

"is" - length = 2 , 9+2+1(whitespace) = 12 < 15 => [1,2,3]

"jack" - length = 4, 12 + 4 = 16 > 15 => DONE! Result = [1,2,3]
```

So, now we know the search result consist of index 1 to 3 of ex1.
That means, our desired result consists of index 1 to 3 of ex2.

Then we can concatenate:

```
ex2[1] + " " + ex2[2] + " " + ex2[3] =
"name{99.03}" + " " + "is{85.37}" + " " + "jack{95.42}" =

"name{99.03} is{85.37} jack{95.42}"

BOOM!
```

Should also work for the case mentioned in comment.

Comment: Thanks, Just what I was looking for.
have added a small code for the upper use case where people can tweak the code as per there use case. Looks more like a palindrome use case after writing the code. 
string[] firstStringList = "My name is jack sparrow:".Split(' ');
string[] secondStringList = "My name{99.03} is{85.37} jack{95.42} 
sparrow:".Split(' ');
bool isMatching = true;
for (int i = 0; i < secondStringList.Length; i++)
{
  if (firstStringList[i] == secondStringList[i])
  {
                    isMatching = false;
  }
}
Console.WriteLine(isMatching);

Comment: ,Do you have a code or any link for the exact use case written by you by any chance? That would be really appreciated